# Python3: Custom Sort

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dictionary and I want to sort frequency from highest to lowest. If two words have the same frequency, then the word with the lower alphabetical order comes first.

I wanted to use [cmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function but apparently this function is deprecated in python 3.

This is what I've done:

```
    dic = {'i': 2, 'like': 2, 'so': 1, 'coding': 1}
    output = [key for key, value in sorted(
        dic.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0), reverse=True)]

    print(output) // ['like', 'i', 'so', 'coding']
```

My desired output is `['i, 'like', 'coding', 'so' ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `-` sign to first element in the sorting key to reverse the order:

```
dic = {'i': 2, 'like': 2, 'so': 1, 'coding': 1}

print([k for k, _ in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda k: (-k[1], k[0]))])
```

Prints:

```
['i', 'like', 'coding', 'so']
```

Comment: Thank you it's working. Just one more question please what if I want to sort descending alphabetically

Comment: Do you mean sort depending on alphabet when both have same size? I didn't understand the question clearly.

Comment: @Melchia If you want to sort from highest frequency and descending alphabetically, then you can do `sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda k: (k[1], k[0]), reverse=True)`, the output would be `['like', 'i', 'so', 'coding']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use key parameter in sorted. It will sort by value which is represented by `x[1]` else choose smallest size which is represented by `-len(x[0])`

`output = [key for key,_ in sorted(dic.items(),key=lambda x: (x[1],-len(x[0])),reverse=True)]`

Output:

`['i', 'like', 'so', 'coding']`

Comment: Actually it's alphabetically but Thanks I see how using the lambda is more powerful than itemgetter

Comment: Yes, in sort function you can provide a full function as key which is quite useful in a lot of cases.